# Tkinter Text widget scroll bar doesn't show the first character

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I am trying to make a horizontal scroll bar for a text widget in tkinter, it works but when the text is long, it starts not showing some parts of the first character untill it's totally disappeared.

[You can see some pixels of the first character in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CnXG.png)

That's my code:

```
scrollbar = Scrollbar(window, orient='horizontal')
scrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

text = Text(window, font=("Calibri", 40), xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
text.tag_configure("center", justify='center')
text.insert("1.0", "222222222222222222222222222222")
text.tag_add("center", "1.0", "end")
text.config(width=100, height=1, background="#f2f2f2", borderwidth=0, state='disabled', wrap='none')
text.pack(pady=24)
scrollbar.config(command=text.xview)
```

Comment: You are trying to center a long line, so part of the line goes beyond the widget's borders. Replace with text.tag_configure("center", justify='left ')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `root.resizable(280, 20)`, try this:

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
root.resizable(280, 20)
root.title("Scrollbar Widget Example")

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root, orient='horizontal')
scrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

text = Text(root, font=("Calibri", 40), xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
text.tag_configure("center", justify='center')
text.insert("1.0", "222222222222222222222222222222")
text.tag_add("center", "1.0", "end")
text.config(width=30, height=1, background="#f2f2f2", borderwidth=0, state='disabled', wrap='none')
scrollbar.config(command=text.xview)
text.pack(pady=24)
 
root.mainloop()
```